# How validate for domain name of email address

Tags: asp.net

I have a form in which user enters email address.I am validating it through java script.I want to validate the Domain name of email address
 What is the best way to validate domain name of email address  in .net ?

Comment: Short answer, there isn't a good way to be honest. You can check the domain looks like a real domain easy enough, but in terms of checking that it is real, even if you ping the domain, there is no guarantee it handles email.

Comment: Does Dns.GetHostByName() gives the  right  answer?

Answer (score 1):

best way for check domain name in Email address is use regular expression
this Expression use for validation email
\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*.\w+([-.]\w+)*
you can edit domain part in this expression \w+([-.]\w+)*\

Comment: I want to know is there any web service which can tell whether this domain exists or not

Answer (score 1):

this webservive is checking domain:
http://www.ecocoma.com/domain_webservice.aspx
you must substring domain name from email address and send to webservice
notice: for testing this webservive, you must online
sample code for working it:

```
protected void btnwhoIs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
try
{
Whois_Service service = new Whois_Service();
Whois whois = new Whois();

service.SoapVersion = SoapProtocolVersion.Soap12;
whois = service.GetWhois("DOM-T36309683M", "", txtWhoIs.Text);

divRes.InnerText = whois.Description;
}
catch (System.Net.WebException ex)
{
divRes.InnerText = ex.Message;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @KingCronus said, there's no good method built in the framework for doing this. The most reliable method I know of is using this commercial component: http://cobisi.com/email-validation/.net-component
I've once done work using it for a client and it seemed reliable. You can use it to detect bogus email services (like http://mailinator.com/), but unfortunately, I don't know of any free component that performs this functionality.